# Why Hibernate requires us to implement equals/hashcode methods when I have a private id field?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, equals, hashcode

First, consider the snippet,

```
public class Employee
{
    private Integer id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastName;
    private String department;
 // public getters and setters here, i said PUBLIC
}
```

I create 2 objects with same ids and rest of all the fields are also same.

```
Employee e1 = new Employee();
Employee e2 = new Employee();

e1.setId(100);
e2.setId(100);

//Prints false in console
System.out.println(e1.equals(e2));
```

The whole problem starts here
***In a real time application, this must return true.***

Consequently, everyone knows a solution exists (to implement equals() and hashcode())

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(o == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (o == this)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (getClass() != o.getClass())
    {
        return false;
    }

    Employee e = (Employee) o;
    return (this.getId() == e.getId());

}
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    final int PRIME = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = PRIME * result + getId();
    return result;
}
```

Now, as usual:

```
        Employee e1 = new Employee();
        Employee e2 = new Employee();

        e1.setId(100);
        e2.setId(100);

        //Prints 'true' now
        System.out.println(e1.equals(e2));

        Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
        employees.add(e1);
        employees.add(e2);

        //Prints ofcourse one objects(which was a requirement)
        System.out.println(employees);
```

I am going through this excellent article [Don't Let Hibernate Steal Your Identity](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html). But one thing I have failed to understand completely. The whole problem and its solution discussed above and the linked article were dealing the problems when the 2 Employee object ids were same.

Consider when we have a **private setter** for ***id field*** with the id field generated by the ***generator class*** provided in ***hbm.xml***. As soon as i start to persist the Employee objects(***and in no way i would be able to change the id***), i find no need to implement equals and hashcode methods. I am sure i am missing something, since my intuition says when a particular concept is too much rotated over the web, it must have always been laid in front of you for the sake of avoiding some common errors ? Do i still have to implement those 2 methods when i have a private setter for id field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the entity defines a natural business key, then you should use that for [`equals`](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-equals-and-hashcode/) and [`hashCode`](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-equals-and-hashcode/). The natural identifier or business key is consistent across all entity state transitions, hence the `hashCode` will not change when the JPA entity state changes (e.g. from New to Managed to Detached).

In your example, you are using the `assigned` identifier, which doesn't change when you persist your entity.

However, if you don't have a natural identifier and you have a generated `PRIMARY KEY` (e.g., `IDENTITY`, `SEQUENCE`), then you can implement equals and hashCode like this:

```
@Entity
public class Book implements Identifiable<Long> {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
 
    private String title;
 
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
 
        if (!(o instanceof Book))
            return false;
 
        Book other = (Book) o;
 
        return id != null &&
               id.equals(other.getId());
    }
 
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }
 
    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

The entity identifier can be used for `equals` and hashCode, but only if the `hashCode` returns the same value all the time. This might sound like a terrible thing to do since it defeats the purpose of using multiple buckets in a `HashSet` or `HashMap`.

However, for performance reasons, you should always limit the number of entities that are stored in a collection. You should never fetch thousands of entities in a `@OneToMany` `Set` because the performance penalty on the database side is multiple orders of magnitude higher than using a single hashed bucket.

The reason why this version of `equals` and `hashCode` works is that the [`hashCode` value does not change from one entity state to another](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/), and the identifier is checked only when it's not `null`.

Comment: You really seem to be conceptually made guy.

Comment: I've never heard that expression, but I assume it's a good thing, right?

Comment: i like your answers. There is point which the author makes in that linked article(Page2), "This is a problem when you want to create domain objects that hold other domain objects in Sets, Maps, or Lists. To do so you must provide an implementation of equals() and hashCode() for each of your objects that is valid both before and after saving the objects and does not change while the objects are in memory." Could you please elaborate on this line. What does he mean by ....while the objects are in memory? Persisted in databse or in VM memory?

Comment: You mention on your site that we can’t use an auto-incrementing database id for comparing objects, since the transient and the attached object versions won’t be equal to each other. But why would I ever consider comparing transient and attached objects, i mean in which context/ scenario?

Comment: Like when you have a Parent, that has a Set of children and you add a Child to the Set and persist the Child.